# Wlan0 interface gone after a reboot

Tags: 14.04, wireless, kubuntu, adapter

I am using kubuntu 14.04 on my HP laptop, but I can't connect to my wifi.
`ifconfig` returns eth0 and lo as the only interfaces.
`ifconfig -a` shows the wlan0 interface. 
Tried `ifconfig wlan0 up` gives `SIOCSIFFLAGS : Input/Output Error`.
This was working before the reboot. How can I ix this?

Comment: Does `sudo ifup wlan0` give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and conect from "wicd" network manager.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing this answer to expand it with an explanation of specifically how to do that.